# React Native Align Self Flex End not working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Pretty simple one, looking to align some text on the left, and some on the right. For this I thought I'd use flexbox with the following code:

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity disabled={isLoading}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.venueImageContainer}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Image style={styles.venueImage} source={ { uri: getImage()} } />
      )}
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text style={styles.venueName}>{venue.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <Text style={styles.personCount}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>)
```

The only styles being referred to via 'Styles.' are for the text color and size. So nothing that could interfere with the flex layout.

So ideally, I'd like I want "Text1" on the far left, and then "Text2" on the far right, but instead I am getting this: 
[image: Image showing flexbox error]

So the parent container gets full width, but the children are not aligning themselves by flex-start or flex-end.

I am new to React / React Native so please go easy on me...

Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `space-between`?

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', backgroundColor:'red'}}>
```

Answer (score 4):

So rather than using 'space-between' as everyone is suggesting (which is just a workaround..), this is the solution:
You have to add "flex:1" in the style where you specify flex-start and flex-end.

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity disabled={isLoading}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.venueImageContainer}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Image style={styles.venueImage} source={ { uri: getImage()} } />
      )}
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red', flex:1}}>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'blue', flex:1}}>
        <Text style={styles.venueName}>{venue.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'green', flex:1}}>
        <Text style={styles.personCount}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it means the end of the `red` view it's on the end of the `green` view itself.
Put a `alignSelf: 'stretch'` on the `red` view, like as follow:

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity disabled={isLoading}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.venueImageContainer}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Image style={styles.venueImage} source={ { uri: getImage()} } />
      )}
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text style={styles.venueName}>{venue.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <Text style={styles.personCount}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>)
```

Or you can use `position: 'absolute` on the green view to change it's position with some fixed values, like as follow:

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity disabled={isLoading}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.venueImageContainer}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Image style={styles.venueImage} source={ { uri: getImage()} } />
      )}
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text style={styles.venueName}>{venue.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', position: 'absolute', right: 10}}>
        <Text style={styles.personCount}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>)
```

Change the `right: 10` value to match your needs.

or put a `justifyContent: 'space-between'` on the `red` view, like as follow:

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity disabled={isLoading}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.venueImageContainer}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Image style={styles.venueImage} source={ { uri: getImage()} } />
      )}
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text style={styles.venueName}>{venue.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <Text style={styles.personCount}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>)
```

but if you want to have more than 2 views inside that red view, one of them would be in the middle, so i dont think you would want that.

(I dont know why your red view stretch's all the way to the end of the view, but it shouldn't, i think (I may be wrong about this))

Comment: Thanks for response, adding a JustifyContent: Space-Between on the red view worked :)

Comment: oh... ok then :(

Answer (score 0):

had some struggles to align the items at the end, but

```
justifyContent: 'flex-end'
```

finally worked

Answer (score -1):

Your solution doesn't work because the CSS property `align-self` is used for the cross axis and `alignSelf` works the same way so it can't be used to align horizontally which is here the main axis.

1. First solution : use `justifyContent: space-between` it works perfectly for your case :

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
                        <Text>Left</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                        <Text>Right</Text>
                    </View>
</View>
```

2. Second solution : use a `View` with `flex: 1` to "fill" the middle space :

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
                        <Text>Left</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                        <Text>Right</Text>
                    </View>
 </View>
```